# Entity Framework - SaveChanges() on my DbContext is not appearing in my intellisense

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

Hopefully I have things set up correctly, and I have implemented this in the past in .net core but my current environment is .net 4.5x. EF version 6.1.x.

My problem is, I am trying to create an Add method, that will class the DbContext's `Add` method. However, when I try and call the `SaveChanges()` from the DbContext, intellisense tells me it doesn't exists. This pattern worked when I had used EF in .net core and online references tell me this is how it should work as well?

Additionally, I came across another stackoverflow post mentioning how the `System.Data.Entity` using statement needed to be added - this is included but still doesn't work.

The code:

```
public class ARepository : DbContext
{
    public RegRepCommodityRepository()
        : base("WhateverConnectionString")
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ARepository>(null);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>().ToTable("dbo.SomeClass");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private DbSet<SomeClass> MyContext { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SomeClass> SelectEverything()
    {
        return MyContext.ToList();
    }

    public void Add(MyClass addThisClass)
    {
        MyContext.Add(addThisClass);
        MyContext.SaveChanges(); // Intellisense tells me that SaveChanges does not exists
    }
}
```

*** EDIT ***

just call `this.SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveChanges()` is not static method, you can't call it without instantiating an object of your `DbContext` class, You can call this instead.

```
this.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah. I feel kind of dumb having being stuck for so long.

Answer (score 2):

SaveChanges() is a method of the **DbContext** and not of the **DbSet**.
DbSet represents one table, the DbContext could represents your db or a part of it. it seems also that you are trying to implement repository pattern in your dbContext class that it's not correct, i suggest you to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 0):

**Try dis** 
instantobj.SaveChanges();

Comment: this can be added in comment. Please explain your answer.

Comment: you can't call it without instantiating an object of your DbContext....firstly you create and then cal it..

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges()` is a method of the `DbContext` and not of the `DbSet`. `DbSet` represents one table, the `DbContext` could represents your db or a part of it. it seems also that you are trying to implement repository pattern in your `dbContext` class that it's not correct, read it for more detail [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)